# Invalid Google Home devices linked to account causes multiple SYNC calls

Tags: actions-on-google

I've been trying to develop smart home app on Google Home assistant.
During development process I've found that after adding **Devices** under **Home Control** section inside mobile app, 
Google Home API calls sync method 4 times.

I found out that I have 4 Google Home devices linked to my account:
[See attached app screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UnS7x.png)

Is there any way to unlink these invalid Google Home devices from my account, which obviously cause the problem?

Answer (score 0):

In [the Google Home app](https://madeby.google.com/home/setup/), you can find your linked devices by clicking on the TV/speaker icon in the top-right corner. From that list, you should be able to unlink the specific devices you want from your Google account.

[Source](https://support.google.com/googlehome/answer/7124017?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en)

Edit: The multiple SYNC calls should not be related to the number of physical Home devices connected to your account.